# 2007 MS Office Auto-correct list not working in 2010 MS Outlook Mail

Tags: autocorrect

I upgraded from Office 2007 to Office 2010, and my auto-correct list works as before in everything except Outlook Mail (Outlook Calendar and Tasks work correctly, also Word, Excel).  It only works correctly in Mail when I'm replying to mail sent in Rich-text format.  How do I get the same auto-correct list to work correctly with Outlook Mail in HTML format?